# Как поставить элементы в исходное положение после нажатия кнопки "Обнулить" js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо обнулять значения в полях, которые выводят результаты и ставить фишки в исходное положение. На картинке показано всё, что нужно обнулять.
[image: счёты]

я пишу функцию, которая по нажатию кнопки "обнулить" - reset, обнуляет поля вывода значений - result, result1, total:

```
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function(e) {
 document.getElementById("result").value = "0";
 document.getElementById("result1").value = "0";
 document.getElementById("total").value = "0";
 document.getElementById("row").style.right = 500+"px";
}
```

а вот с перемещением фишек - row проблема. пробовала через стили - не то.

```js
let rows = document.querySelector('.rows');

rows.onclick = e => {
  let tar = e.target;

  if (tar.classList.contains('fishka')) {
    let row = tar.closest('.row');
    let sep = row.querySelector('.separator');

    let taken = +row.dataset.taken;
    let index = +tar.dataset.idx;

    if (sep) sep.classList.remove('separator');
    let newIdx = index + (index >= taken);
    let newSep = row.querySelector(`.fishka[data-idx="${newIdx}"]`);
    if (newSep) newSep.classList.add('separator');
    row.dataset.taken = newIdx;

    calcRowSum(row);
  }
}

function calcRowSum(row) {
  let output = row.previousElementSibling;
  output.value = row.dataset.taken * row.dataset.mult;
  calcTotal();
}

function calcTotal() {
  let rowSums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row-sum')];
  total.value = rowSums.reduce((a, v) => +v.value + a, 0);
}

/*кнопка обнуления*/

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function(e) {
  document.getElementById("result").value = "0";
    document.getElementById("result1").value = "0";
    document.getElementById("total").value = "0";

    document.getElementById("row").style.right = 500+"px";

}
```

```css
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #EEE9E1;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 58px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

section {
    padding-top: 113px;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

ul, li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

 /*переключатель, скрывающий результат, поле вывода суммы и кнопка для переключения уровня*/
.menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
position: relative;
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
width: 1500px;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/*стили для переключателя, который скрывает результаты*/
label { margin: 2em;}
input { display: none;}
input+label,
input+label::before,
input+label::after {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
}
input+label { /*поле, по которому ездит переключатель*/
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 64px;
    cursor: pointer;

border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 30px;
}

input+label::before { /*текст*/
    display: block;
    content: attr(data-off-label);
    position: absolute;

    right: 10px;
    color: #fff;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 60px;

}

/*стиль кружочка слева*/
input+label::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;

    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #96683B;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+label::before { /*стиль текста справа*/
    content: attr(data-on-label);
    left: 14px;
    right: auto;
    color: #fff;
}

/*стиль кружочка справа*/
input:checked+label::after {
    left: 87px;
    width: 56px;
height: 56px;
background: #E2C898;
}

#demo1+label {  background-color: #E2C898; } /*цвет на выкл*/
#demo1+label::before {  color: #96683B; } /*цвет текста на выкл*/
#demo1:checked+label {  background-color: #96683B;} /*цвет на вкл*/
#demo1:checked+label::before { color: #E2C898; } /*цвет текста на вкл*/

 /*поле вывода суммы*/
.total {
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 511px;
height: 64px;
background: #96683B;
border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #96683B;
border-radius: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 56px;
color: #F9F9F9;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
justify-content: center;
overflow: auto;
}

/*кнопка для смены уровня*/
.level{
    box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
width: 339px;
height: 64px;
margin-left: -150px;
top: 50px;
background: #96683B;
border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 20px;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 28px;
line-height: 56px;
text-align: center;
color: #F9F9F9;
}


/*Рамка со спицами (подложка)-игровое поле*/
.pole{
background: url('../img/1.svg') no-repeat center top / cover;
width: 700px;
height: 818.87px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: -50px;
}


/*Класс, в котором заключены все ряды и поля для вывода значений, набранных на каждом ряду*/
.rows {
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-width: 360px;
}


/*Поля для вывода значений, набранных на каждом ряду*/
.row-sum {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;

width: 250px;
height: 50px;
background: #DAB26A;
border: 3px solid #96683B;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 20px;

font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 38px;
line-height: 56px;
text-align: center;

color: #F9F9F9;
margin-left: -370px;
}

#result1{
margin-top: -30px;
}

/*Класс, в котором лежат все фишки-ряды*/
.row {
display: flex;
margin-top: -55px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
margin-right: 80px;
margin-left: 60px;
gap: 2px;

}

/*Стили для фишек*/
.fishka{
 cursor: pointer;

}


/*Разделение фишек*/
.separator {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.task{
margin-left: 760px;
margin-top:  -740px;
}


.reset{
    box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
width: 339px;
height: 64px;
margin-left: 760px;
top: 45px;
background: #96683B;
border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 20px;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 28px;
line-height: 56px;
text-align: center;
color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<article class="abacus" >

<!-- Кнопка для скрывания результатов, Результат вычислений и кнопка "перейти на уровень 2" -->
<section id="menu">

<div class="menu">

  <div class="check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="demo1" checked>
  <label for="demo1" data-on-label="Вкл." data-off-label="Выкл."></label>
  </div>

    <output name="total" id="total" class="total">0</output>

    <button name="level" value="level" class="level">
    УРОВЕНЬ 2
    </button>

</div>

</section>


<!-- Игровое поле, которое состоит из рамки, спиц и фишек -->
<section id="pole" class="pole">
<div class="rows">

<output id="result1" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1000000000">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
  <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="100000000">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
      <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
      <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
  </div>

 <output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
    <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="10000000">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
      <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
      <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
    </div>

    <output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
      <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1000000">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
      </div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="100000">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="10000">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1000">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="100">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="10">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>

<div id="row" class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1" transform="0px">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>
</div>

<div class="task">
  <img src="img/задание.svg" width="339" height="297" alt="">
</div>

<button type="button" onClick="refreshPage()" name="reset" id="reset" value="reset" class="reset">
ОБНУЛИТЬ
</button>

</section>
</article>

<script src="js/test.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Покажите стили и разметку, с которой возникли сложности

Comment: добавила в вопрос

Comment: У картинок "двигается" класс `separator`... Для сброса его нужно убрать у всех картинок и потом добавить картинкам с `data-idx="0"`.